# Run Linux command from Angular 4 component

Tags: linux, angular, typescript

Requirement is to fetch the output of a shell script's after running it from the Angular 4 component at the beginning during compilation i.e. just before the website is launched. I have already gone through the threads in stackoverflow  i.e. [49700941](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49700941/run-any-linux-terminal-command-from-typescript) and [41637166](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41637166/8337391).

From the first thread i tried to use the below code, but getting error:

**Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in 'app/component ...'**

```
const exec = require('child_process').exec;   // Can't resolve 'child_process' error coming from this line

exec('/home/myDir/init_setup.sh', (err, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (err){
       console.error(err);
       return;
    };
    console.log(stdout);
    console.log(stderr);
    /** 
     remaining logics
    */
});
```

Please let me know if I need to import some library explicitly or not to avoid this error.

Comment: You can't do that on Angular. The examples for nodejs that you read.

Comment: Yes! you are right @selmansamet. Thanks for replying. But is there any other ways rather workaround to fulfill this requirement? Any idea you can share..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The modern browsers opens the webpage in isolated sandbox so they have have no access to clients' computers.
Imagine the damage that could be done if a black hat could run batch script on computer that opens his webpage.

The only way to run the script is to run the desktop application on client's machine.

The example code you provided is Node.js code, the desktop framework that user have to install on his machine and run the code intentionally. There's (**fortunately!**) no way to run it remotely via webpage.

Comment: Got it! Thanks for the explanation @Paulie